# Passing parameter to a running service thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, parameters

I've MP3 playing Service that has its own class and uses Mediaplayer and connects with HTTP. It must play one of URLs selected in previous Activity, that I pass to PlayerActivity.

I create Service this way in the `PlayerActivity onCreate`:

```
         startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
         Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
         bindService(connectionIntent, mp3PlayerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Here is the first selected URL launch. I launch Mediaplayer call in the new Thread not to block UI (the call is in `ActivityPlayer` by itself):

```
private ServiceConnection mp3PlayerServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder binder) {
        mp3Service = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            mp3Service.playSong(getApplicationContext(),url);

        }
        };

        t.start();


    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {

    }
 };
```

The problem is how to pass a new URL to this Service's thread, when user destroys this Activity, goes to the menu and selects new URL. The new stream must play in the same thread, but I had situations that going back to Home with back button and launching app again I got 2 URLs playing simultaneously. Maybe cause of new `Thread()` declaration.

So, when Activity creates with a URL, how to pass its URL right to Service's thread, so if it is the old URL, nothing happens, and if it is new, the player switches to new URL, but not playing 2 streams together?

Comment: Are you returning the same Binder on bindService or a new one?

Comment: Here is the code from Service class: `public final IBinder localBinder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return localBinder;
    }

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to communicate through broadcasts? You could implement a nested `BroadcastReceiver` in the service (and if need be in the activity) and just send signals to it from an activity.

If there is any private data you could use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to keep it from being system wide.

EDIT:

For other uses, there's also Android Interface Definition Language.

Comment: Maybe I've seen something about this but the Service usually meets first, so I choosed more simple way (at least for beginners in Android)...

Comment: Could you say something about Thread use here? Is there a possible buggy place for 2 Threads appearing simultaneously?

Comment: You could specify in the manifest `process=:process_desc`. The `:`will make the service run in it's own process.